# Im trying to figure out how to access an image from the android default gallery and email it

Tags: android, image, email, photo, send

I've figured out how to access the default gallery, and I've figured out how to use the email function for text but I wanna email images in my gallery, how do I do this? I was going to try and use the code bellow but an error keeps poping up for "getTempUri", what am I overlooking, I appreciate any help on this. Thanks

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
    Intent photosendbutton = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    photosendbutton.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    photosendbutton.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"johnnywalker@hotmail.com"}); 
    photosendbutton.setType("image/*");
    Uri parse = getTempUri("/mnt/sdcard/yourfolder");
    photosendbutton.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, parse);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(photosendbutton, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: What is the error that pops up for `getTempUri`?

Comment: The method getTempUri(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Where is the `getTempUri(String)` method implemented? Please **edit** your post and add any and all relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to access a method from within an onclicklistener. The method getTempUri is defined outside the onClickListener, but you probably don't see it because the onClickListener is declared inline like this:

```
class YourContainingClass{

   public Uri getTempUri(String){
      //process string
   }

   public void someOtherMethod(){
      button.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
            //this is where you're trying to access getTempUri,
            //from within the new OnClickListener instance
         }
      });
   }
}
```

You can solve this by accessing getTempUri like this, if your containing class is an Activity:

```
((YourContainingClass)v.getContext()).getTempUri()
```

otherwise you can let your containing class implement onClickListener like this:

```
class YourContainingClass implements OnClickListener
{
   public void someMethod(){
      button.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void OnClick(View v){
      //put your code here, here you have access to getTepUri
      this.getTempUri();
   }

   public Uri getTempUri(String someString){
      //your logic
   }
}
```

I realize this may be hard to follow, but try it out and feel free to ask questions